# Can you pass a JavaScript variable using __doPostBack() to VB.net?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am just wondering, is it possible to pass a JavaScript variable to server side VB.net using `__doPostBack()`?

Comment: One option might be to have a hidden input like `<input type="hidden" name="input1" id="input1" runat="server" />` and use javascript to set the value of it `document.getElementById("input1").value = "somevalue"`. Then when you get back to your code behind you can probably get to it. (I'm fuzzy on the ID thing though. Can't remember if .Net forms changes the id name. Might need `getElementsByName("input1")[0]` instead.